# Parse JSON data from a website with HTTP request with javascript

Tags: javascript, instagram

I've used package sniffer to get a specific endpoint, which gave me a direct JSON url. Now I want to get for all usernames from this JSON format.For eg. it goes like this:

```
{"node":{"id":"1428809588","username":"kafeterijabg","full_name":"\u041a\u0430\u0444\u0435\u0442\u0435\u0440\u0438\u0458\u0430\u00ae","profile_pic_url":"https://instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/65f96409e2a6c5b9b72cda956aa0dfea/5E638B5F/t51.2885-19/s150x150/64620072_350924665805634_2914908438809018368_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net","is_private":false,"is_verified":false,"followed_by_viewer":true,"requested_by_viewer":false,"reel":{"id":"1428809588","expiring_at":1572193230,"has_pride_media":false,"latest_reel_media":1572095740,"seen":1572031349,"owner":{"__typename":"GraphUser","id":"1428809588","profile_pic_url":"https://instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/65f96409e2a6c5b9b72cda956aa0dfea/5E638B5F/t51.2885-19/s150x150/64620072_350924665805634_2914908438809018368_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net","username":"kafeterijabg"}}}}
```

I've tried sending requests and parsing it to console but I'm getting "undefined".

```
function Get(yourUrl){
    var Httpreq = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    Httpreq.open("GET",yourUrl,false);
    Httpreq.send(null);
    return Httpreq.responseText;
}
var json_obj = JSON.parse(Get(MYURL));
console.log(json_obj.username);
```

I've never done anything similar before.

EDIT1:

It seems like I was using the wrong endpoint.But when I just try to get the output of the request without parsing it I'm getting only first two lines of It, even tho when I open the endpoint in browser I'm seeing all of it.
This is what I'm getting:

```
{"data":{"user":{"edge_follow":{"count":377,"page_info":{"has_next_page":false,"end_cursor":null},"edges":[]}}},"status":"ok"}
```

And here is what I expected to get.

```
{"data":{"user":{"edge_follow":{"count":377,"page_info":{"has_next_page":true,"end_cursor":"QVFBd2J1MzJKakRoNXI3bzVqR1hTYkRYRjJ0TGJrNjJxeFVnRmVsc0JwczZLR1d3VXloZDA4NXFiUFV6dXU4RlRfck93M0J5Z1ZINVdieEtwREVmWFZNaA=="},"edges":[{"node":{"id":"8752655712","username":"dragibravo","full_name":"Dragi Bravo \u00a9","profile_pic_url":"https://instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/5f53d36c1e430cbd5453478159c0a780/5E4CE6DD/t51.2885-19/s150x150/44656034_343135116439319_1392780490192191488_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net","is_private":false,"is_verified":false,"followed_by_viewer":true,"requested_by_viewer":false,"reel":{"id":"8752655712","expiring_at":1572210555,"has_pride_media":false,"latest_reel_media":1572123916,"seen":1572085057,"owner":{"__typename":"GraphUser","id":"8752655712","profile_pic_url":"https://instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/5f53d36c1e430cbd5453478159c0a780/5E4CE6DD/t51.2885-19/s150x150/44656034_343135116439319_1392780490192191488_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net","username":"dragibravo"}}}},{"node":{"id":"21396562691","username":"dete_devedesetih","full_name":"detedevedesetih","profile_pic_url":"https://instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/88d2c2221aaa75ca2ea16ab32d0f1578/5E42CEE5/t51.2885-19/s150x150/69694071_2580132948676320_8436138521869156352_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net","is_private":false,"is_verified":false,"followed_by_viewer":true,"requested_by_viewer":false,"reel":{"id":"21396562691","expiring_at":1572210555,"has_pride_media":false,"latest_reel_media":1572123552,"seen":null,"owner":{"__typename":"GraphUser","id":"21396562691","profile_pic_url":"https://instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/88d2c2221aaa75ca2ea16ab32d0f1578/5E42CEE5/t51.2885-19/s150x150/69694071_2580132948676320_8436138521869156352_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net","username":"dete_devedesetih"}}}},{"node":{"id":"14659853","username":"brittanya187","full_name":"Brittanya Razavi","profile_pic_url":"https://instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/f611badd19896aad1280c5743b4692d5/5E5907C2/t51.2885-19/s150x150/42002550_2204067873162229_8645854606632419328_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net","is_private":false,"is_verified":true,"followed_by_viewer":true,"requested_by_viewer":false,"reel":{"id":"14659853","expiring_at":1572210555,"has_pride_media":false,"latest_reel_media":1572121817,"seen":1572039263,"owner":{"__typename":"GraphUser","id":"14659853","profile_pic_url":"https://instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/f611badd19896aad1280c5743b4692d5/5E5907C2/t51.2885-19/s150x150/42002550_2204067873162229_8645854606632419328_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net","username":"brittanya187"}}}},{"node":{"id":"1465895116","username":"britnibrid","full_name":"neispavana lepotica","profile_pic_url":"https://instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/ce45b2702afa309ca3c581dbd99ba68f/5E5A1E14/t51.2885-19/s150x150/44828900_327180521439297_1922646860288229376_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net","is_private":false,"is_verified":false,"followed_by_viewer":true,"requested_by_viewer":false,"reel":{"id":"1465895116","expiring_at":1572210555,"has_pride_media":false,"latest_reel_media":0,"seen":null,"owner":{"__typename":"GraphUser","id":"1465895116","profile_pic_url":"https://instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/ce45b2702afa309ca3c581dbd99ba68f/5E5A1E14/t51.2885-19/s150x150/44828900_327180521439297_1922646860288229376_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net","username":"britnibrid"}}}},{"node":{"id":"1428809588","username":"kafeterijabg","full_name":"\u041a\u0430\u0444\u0435\u0442\u0435\u0440\u0438\u0458\u0430\u00ae","profile_pic_url":"https://instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/65f96409e2a6c5b9b72cda956aa0dfea/5E638B5F/t51.2885-19/s150x150/64620072_350924665805634_2914908438809018368_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net","is_private":false,"is_verified":false,"followed_by_viewer":true,"requested_by_viewer":false,"reel":{"id":"1428809588","expiring_at":1572210555,"has_pride_media":false,"latest_reel_media":1572107760,"seen":1572107760,"owner":{"__typename":"GraphUser","id":"1428809588","profile_pic_url":"https://instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/65f96409e2a6c5b9b72cda956aa0dfea/5E638B5F/t51.2885-19/s150x150/64620072_350924665805634_2914908438809018368_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net","username":"kafeterijabg"}}}},{"node":{"id":"13795435410","username":"jacobs_rs","full_name":"JacobsSrbija","profile_pic_url":"https://instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/4363dbdcf8e8a94bc65968dd4907ff60/5E64F5DB/t51.2885-19/s150x150/60911497_2333358360317600_4108961307611365376_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net","is_private":false,"is_verified":false,"followed_by_viewer":true,"requested_by_viewer":false,"reel":{"id":"13795435410","expiring_at":1572210555,"has_pride_media":false,"latest_reel_media":1572081948,"seen":1572081948,"owner":{"__typename":"GraphUser","id":"13795435410","profile_pic_url":"https://instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/4363dbdcf8e8a94bc65968dd4907ff60/5E64F5DB/t51.2885-19/s150x150/60911497_2333358360317600_4108961307611365376_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net","username":"jacobs_rs"}}}},{"node":{"id":"6706638255","username":"apartment_a6_kopaonik","full_name":"Apartment A6 Kopaonik \u00ae","profile_pic_url":"https://instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/db9d49897114fb812add6b89f60198da/5E54AB81/t51.2885-19/s150x150/45378715_351931902032023_3560095462486704128_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net","is_private":false,"is_verified":false,"followed_by_viewer":true,"requested_by_viewer":false,"reel":{"id":"6706638255","expiring_at":1572210555,"has_pride_media":false,"latest_reel_media":0,"seen":1572023751,"owner":{"__typename":"GraphUser","id":"6706638255","profile_pic_url":"https://instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/db9d49897114fb812add6b89f60198da/5E54AB81/t51.2885-19/s150x150/45378715_351931902032023_3560095462486704128_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net","username":"apartment_a6_kopaonik"}}}},{"node":{"id":"21433171875","username":"dugestaze_svilajnac","full_name":"DUGE STAZE","profile_pic_url":"https://instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/d5e220b083bfb4432cd6f4dda3a81ba7/5E47E625/t51.2885-19/s150x150/71523182_308405693359685_2542825728215351296_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net","is_private":false,"is_verified":false,"followed_by_viewer":true,"requested_by_viewer":false,"reel":{"id":"21433171875","expiring_at":1572210555,"has_pride_media":false,"latest_reel_media":0,"seen":null,"owner":{"__typename":"GraphUser","id":"21433171875","profile_pic_url":"https://instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/d5e220b083bfb4432cd6f4dda3a81ba7/5E47E625/t51.2885-19/s150x150/71523182_308405693359685_2542825728215351296_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net","username":"dugestaze_svilajnac"}}}},{"node":{"id":"280846376","username":"dekstroza","full_name":"dekstroza","profile_pic_url":"https://instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/838e15717ddeba3ff12d82657f3fa30e/5E5F3CCB/t51.2885-19/s150x150/70473686_396716634369751_3090030692306780160_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net","is_private":false,"is_verified":false,"followed_by_viewer":true,"requested_by_viewer":false,"reel":{"id":"280846376","expiring_at":1572210555,"has_pride_media":false,"latest_reel_media":1572101572,"seen":1572101572,"owner":{"__typename":"GraphUser","id":"280846376","profile_pic_url":"https://instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/838e15717ddeba3ff12d82657f3fa30e/5E5F3CCB/t51.2885-19/s150x150/70473686_396716634369751_3090030692306780160_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net","username":"dekstroza"}}}},{"node":{"id":"6619361585","username":"ozbiljne_teme","full_name":"Ozbiljne Teme","profile_pic_url":"https://instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/e56294e9abfe45f7c2ae2de54d208557/5E50CBDA/t51.2885-19/s150x150/53740023_372495643602512_1074420510437146624_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net","is_private":false,"is_verified":false,"followed_by_viewer":true,"requested_by_viewer":false,"reel":{"id":"6619361585","expiring_at":1572210555,"has_pride_media":false,"latest_reel_media":1572099187,"seen":1572099187,"owner":{"__typename":"GraphUser","id":"6619361585","profile_pic_url":"https://instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/e56294e9abfe45f7c2ae2de54d208557/5E50CBDA/t51.2885-19/s150x150/53740023_372495643602512_1074420510437146624_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net","username":"ozbiljne_teme"}}}},{"node":{"id":"706629897","username":"mylifeaskitty","full_name":"Marija Zdravkovi\u0107","profile_pic_url":"https://instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/ac6a53a0cb435d9900ee3984d153ae45/5E5C08E3/t51.2885-19/s150x150/66851574_2354137708132240_8606310035284295680_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net","is_private":false,"is_verified":false,"followed_by_viewer":true,"requested_by_viewer":false,"reel":{"id":"706629897","expiring_at":1572210555,"has_pride_media":false,"latest_reel_media":0,"seen":null,"owner":{"__typename":"GraphUser","id":"706629897","profile_pic_url":"https://instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/ac6a53a0cb435d9900ee3984d153ae45/5E5C08E3/t51.2885-19/s150x150/66851574_2354137708132240_8606310035284295680_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net","username":"mylifeaskitty"}}}},{"node":{"id":"192815961","username":"gordongram","full_name":"Gordon Ramsay","profile_pic_url":"https://instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/ca58f7dd68612bc05924e171092bcecf/5E579BFC/t51.2885-19/s150x150/26429265_1801356139896204_7973709430447407104_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net","is_private":false,"is_verified":true,"followed_by_viewer":true,"requested_by_viewer":false,"reel":{"id":"192815961","expiring_at":1572210555,"has_pride_media":false,"latest_reel_media":0,"seen":null,"owner":{"__typename":"GraphUser","id":"192815961","profile_pic_url":"https://instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/ca58f7dd68612bc05924e171092bcecf/5E579BFC/t51.2885-19/s150x150/26429265_1801356139896204_7973709430447407104_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net","username":"gordongram"}}}},{"node":{"id":"19841914826","username":"vandometa_vlog","full_name":"","profile_pic_url":"https://instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/2d6c970339a04d31010618e05763e7c1/5E431AE5/t51.2885-19/s150x150/67943135_2416133855379280_5169818650630160384_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net","is_private":false,"is_verified":false,"followed_by_viewer":true,"requested_by_viewer":false,"reel":{"id":"19841914826","expiring_at":1572210555,"has_pride_media":false,"latest_reel_media":0,"seen":null,"owner":{"__typename":"GraphUser","id":"19841914826","profile_pic_url":"https://instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/2d6c970339a04d31010618e05763e7c1/5E431AE5/t51.2885-19/s150x150/67943135_2416133855379280_5169818650630160384_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net","username":"vandometa_vlog"}}}},{"node":{"id":"203227483","username":"tommycashworld","full_name":"TOMM\u00a5 \u20acA$H","profile_pic_url":"https://instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/130807ffdb11359677afba2220b62875/5E617C39/t51.2885-19/s150x150/73307916_1416703575159030_5557531713581613056_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net","is_private":false,"is_verified":true,"followed_by_viewer":true,"requested_by_viewer":false,"reel":{"id":"203227483","expiring_at":1572210555,"has_pride_media":false,"latest_reel_media":0,"seen":null,"owner":{"__typename":"GraphUser","id":"203227483","profile_pic_url":"https://instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/130807ffdb11359677afba2220b62875/5E617C39/t51.2885-19/s150x150/73307916_1416703575159030_5557531713581613056_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net","username":"tommycashworld"}}}},{"node":{"id":"4060156840","username":"fourtwenty","full_name":"Four Twenty","profile_pic_url":"https://instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/2d1136bc4a84cfbf432655ebd98e4070/5E5EE4DC/t51.2885-19/s150x150/70594066_1368719939948662_8046432933394776064_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net","is_private":true,"is_verified":false,"followed_by_viewer":true,"requested_by_viewer":false,"reel":{"id":"4060156840","expiring_at":1572210555,"has_pride_media":false,"latest_reel_media":0,"seen":null,"owner":{"__typename":"GraphUser","id":"4060156840","profile_pic_url":"https://instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/2d1136bc4a84cfbf432655ebd98e4070/5E5EE4DC/t51.2885-19/s150x150/70594066_1368719939948662_8046432933394776064_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net","username":"fourtwenty"}}}},{"node":{"id":"6945680089","username":"lazybrain.ai","full_name":"LazyBrain Initiative","profile_pic_url":"https://instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/8b8324c443ffe3de2aa80641d2a9a8de/5E5BE2F3/t51.2885-19/s150x150/27879053_781778075349644_4543882190064189440_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net","is_private":false,"is_verified":false,"followed_by_viewer":true,"requested_by_viewer":false,"reel":{"id":"6945680089","expiring_at":1572210555,"has_pride_media":false,"latest_reel_media":0,"seen":null,"owner":{"__typename":"GraphUser","id":"6945680089","profile_pic_url":"https://instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/8b8324c443ffe3de2aa80641d2a9a8de/5E5BE2F3/t51.2885-19/s150x150/27879053_781778075349644_4543882190064189440_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net","username":"lazybrain.ai"}}}},{"node":{"id":"17100242394","username":"lifewith_crohn","full_name":"Mb.Crohn","profile_pic_url":"https://instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/916a9a84175036f50a6a598457759364/5E41A323/t51.2885-19/s150x150/66674988_2903343653224618_4794522445505626112_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net","is_private":false,"is_verified":false,"followed_by_viewer":true,"requested_by_viewer":false,"reel":{"id":"17100242394","expiring_at":1572210555,"has_pride_media":false,"latest_reel_media":0,"seen":null,"owner":{"__typename":"GraphUser","id":"17100242394","profile_pic_url":"https://instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/916a9a84175036f50a6a598457759364/5E41A323/t51.2885-19/s150x150/66674988_2903343653224618_4794522445505626112_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net","username":"lifewith_crohn"}}}},{"node":{"id":"5355293","username":"andy_mann","full_name":"Andy Mann","profile_pic_url":"https://instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/e12200c75630dc7e1b2b814cb649d066/5E5E764B/t51.2885-19/s150x150/68862836_2425862274407548_3512337272991121408_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net","is_private":false,"is_verified":true,"followed_by_viewer":true,"requested_by_viewer":false,"reel":{"id":"5355293","expiring_at":1572210555,"has_pride_media":false,"latest_reel_media":0,"seen":null,"owner":{"__typename":"GraphUser","id":"5355293","profile_pic_url":"https://instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/e12200c75630dc7e1b2b814cb649d066/5E5E764B/t51.2885-19/s150x150/68862836_2425862274407548_3512337272991121408_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net","username":"andy_mann"}}}},{"node":{"id":"47457589","username":"istrahinja","full_name":"BJJ SANDMAN","profile_pic_url":"https://instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/a378f9ecc6df8cd0018088b6cfc5a5f5/5E4FC0A4/t51.2885-19/s150x150/19051700_1874715819469896_2141424226534424576_a.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net","is_private":true,"is_verified":false,"followed_by_viewer":true,"requested_by_viewer":false,"reel":{"id":"47457589","expiring_at":1572210555,"has_pride_media":false,"latest_reel_media":0,"seen":null,"owner":{"__typename":"GraphUser","id":"47457589","profile_pic_url":"https://instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/a378f9ecc6df8cd0018088b6cfc5a5f5/5E4FC0A4/t51.2885-19/s150x150/19051700_1874715819469896_2141424226534424576_a.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net","username":"istrahinja"}}}},{"node":{"id":"2158133293","username":"mpudja21","full_name":"\u041c\u0438\u0445\u0430\u0438\u043b\u043e \u041f\u0443\u0452\u0430","profile_pic_url":"https://instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/881e653f5d56d596133577f67a4a7e11/5E55C1F8/t51.2885-19/s150x150/74693418_1328190550698806_2099261116705144832_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net","is_private":false,"is_verified":false,"followed_by_viewer":true,"requested_by_viewer":false,"reel":{"id":"2158133293","expiring_at":1572210555,"has_pride_media":false,"latest_reel_media":0,"seen":1572031575,"owner":{"__typename":"GraphUser","id":"2158133293","profile_pic_url":"https://instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/881e653f5d56d596133577f67a4a7e11/5E55C1F8/t51.2885-19/s150x150/74693418_1328190550698806_2099261116705144832_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net","username":"mpudja21"}}}},{"node":{"id":"3998316794","username":"nature","full_name":"Nature","profile_pic_url":"https://instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/2a4e907cbba6de380a178c95bc560376/5E49D099/t51.2885-19/s150x150/37130772_219216685405605_2651841279612157952_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net","is_private":false,"is_verified":false,"followed_by_viewer":true,"requested_by_viewer":false,"reel":{"id":"3998316794","expiring_at":1572210555,"has_pride_media":false,"latest_reel_media":0,"seen":null,"owner":{"__typename":"GraphUser","id":"3998316794","profile_pic_url":"https://instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/2a4e907cbba6de380a178c95bc560376/5E49D099/t51.2885-19/s150x150/37130772_219216685405605_2651841279612157952_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net","username":"nature"}}}},{"node":{"id":"1808243250","username":"dobrotamilica","full_name":"\u13a0\u273a\u266d\u053b\u273a\u0442\u0394","profile_pic_url":"https://instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/2b00e1cb3545393726a0bf1236e6c678/5E5DA2A1/t51.2885-19/s150x150/68908088_518976712264164_5633269725225025536_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net","is_private":true,"is_verified":false,"followed_by_viewer":true,"requested_by_viewer":false,"reel":{"id":"1808243250","expiring_at":1572210555,"has_pride_media":false,"latest_reel_media":1572114311,"seen":1572114311,"owner":{"__typename":"GraphUser","id":"1808243250","profile_pic_url":"https://instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/2b00e1cb3545393726a0bf1236e6c678/5E5DA2A1/t51.2885-19/s150x150/68908088_518976712264164_5633269725225025536_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net","username":"dobrotamilica"}}}},{"node":{"id":"8738182557","username":"majceezmajcee","full_name":"Marija Palurovic","profile_pic_url":"https://instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/ec6c203798b97791d8b0b6f1184f30d1/5E4FFACB/t51.2885-19/s150x150/57198888_414265232485760_3344820921243271168_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net","is_private":true,"is_verified":false,"followed_by_viewer":true,"requested_by_viewer":false,"reel":{"id":"8738182557","expiring_at":1572210555,"has_pride_media":false,"latest_reel_media":0,"seen":null,"owner":{"__typename":"GraphUser","id":"8738182557","profile_pic_url":"https://instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/ec6c203798b97791d8b0b6f1184f30d1/5E4FFACB/t51.2885-19/s150x150/57198888_414265232485760_3344820921243271168_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net","username":"majceezmajcee"}}}},{"node":{"id":"1637485905","username":"niinamilanovic","full_name":"\u2664 N I N A \u2664","profile_pic_url":"https://instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/ade9b86fc3985e70ab7c367b2cae4a26/5E50F5B7/t51.2885-19/s150x150/46354126_723371064697517_1754088811467374592_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net","is_private":false,"is_verified":false,"followed_by_viewer":true,"requested_by_viewer":false,"reel":{"id":"1637485905","expiring_at":1572210555,"has_pride_media":false,"latest_reel_media":0,"seen":null,"owner":{"__typename":"GraphUser","id":"1637485905","profile_pic_url":"https://instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/ade9b86fc3985e70ab7c367b2cae4a26/5E50F5B7/t51.2885-19/s150x150/46354126_723371064697517_1754088811467374592_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbeg5-1.fna.fbcdn.net","username":"niinamilanovic"}}}}]}}},"status":"ok"}
```

EDIT 2:
Cookies were the problem, thats I was getting an empty JSON.

But I still dont know why

```
console.log(json_obj.node.username);
```

does not work.
It gives me this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined
    at :10:32

EDIT 3:
I've solved it with this code:

```
for (const node of json_obj.data.user.edge_follow.edges)
          console.log(node.node.username);
```

Comment: Is there a reason this is tagged with Node.js?  Are you using some XHR polyfill on the server?

Comment: My mistake, I've removed the tag. Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 1):

in the json you posted above there is no tag username. To get to the user name you need to do json_obj.node.username

Comment: Now I'm getting: TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined

Comment: verify the responce of the Get function in the console before feeding it to the parser, dump the output ot the parser in the console. In all modern browsers it should let you browse the tree the parser generated.

Comment: {"message": "Variables are invalid JSON.", "status": "fail"}

What that means?

Comment: it means that the call you are making to the api is invalid. So the api(endpoint) returns that you are not passing the right data, and a a fail status.

Comment: What would you suggest me to do?

Comment: I have no idea. Provided you have documentation of the api you are trying to connect, refer to it, or contact its provider for more information. Given that you are trying to pull usernames list by packet sniffing, however I don't think that is the case, so I guess you are on your own.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like I'm on my own. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Hey, check the post for heads up, I have edited it.

Comment: you are getting an empty response(no pages), but this is definitely a step in the right direction. I suspect you need to set a proper header for the request to work. Check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/setRequestHeader. You may also want to check the network tab in the developer console to see what is happening in terms of header data.

Answer (score 0):

`XMLHttpRequest` is asynchronous, meaning that calling `.open()` and then `.send()` doesn't mean the request is complete after these calls.

Instead, you should set a function to the `.onreadystatechange` property like this:

```
var Httpreq = new XMLHttpRequest(); 

Httpreq.onreadystatechange = function() {
  var json_obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText;
  console.log(json_obj.username);
};

Httpreq.open("GET",yourUrl,false);
Httpreq.send(null);
```

Comment: Yup, I wasn't as accurate as t.stv was - the structure of the JSON object was the issue here.

Comment: When I'd tried his suggestion I got:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined